# Asynchronous call and context

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous

Is it possible to call a function asynchronously with the same context as the main function without sending the context in parameters?

### For Instance

**Method1**:

- Do some work...
- Call `Method2` asynchronously (with taks or delegate etc...) without sending any context in parameters
- Do some other work...

**Method2**:

- Start with the context of `Method1` (without setting a context)
- Do some work...

I'm working on a console (C#/.NET) project that is supposed to run on a server.
EDIT : I forgot to say : I'm working with VS 2010 (no Async/Await)

I need this because some personal object work with the context.

Comment: How would the Method2 determine, which context to use?

Comment: It's the topic of my question...
Is it possible that the context would be set without doing anything in Method2.
The call in Method1 would do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Absolutely.  The common pattern to do this is to encapsulate everything needed in your context into a single class object.  If you only have a single context, and don't intend to ever have multiple concurrent calls, you don't *have to* separate it into its own class.  (NOTE: You need to to really be sure there are no edge cases that violate this before taking this shortcut.)  But it is much cleaner to do so, and not much additional work.

There are numerous ways to do this, one of them is below.

```
public class ExampleClass
{
    private object _myContextInfo; //This can be multiple objects, or a single structured object or whatever you need.
    public void Main()
    {
        _myContextInfo = new object();//Set this to whatever you need
        var bw = new BackgroundWorker();
        bw.DoWork += DoSomethingAsync;
        bw.RunWorkerCompleted += TakeActionOnCompletion;
        bw.RunWorkerAsync();

        //Do whatever you want done in parallel to your other item here
    }

    private void DoSomethingAsync(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        //Do whatever you need and use the class fields however you want;
    }

    private void TakeActionOnCompletion(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Use the results however you need and read/manipulte the class fields however you want;
    }
```

Comment: There are obviously a hundred stylistic patterns and practices opinions on which way is best to do this, but I am choosing to simply answer the posted question, and stay away from any patterns and practices commentary.

Comment: Thanks for the help !
I now can use it as i wanted.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question right, you'll probably need a private attribute for that.
You create a class with every Property you need to manipulate between them and store it in a place where both methods can access.
Something along the lines of:

```
//  Context class you create
public class Ctx{
    //  context data properties
    //  methods, etc
}


public class DoStuff{

    private Ctx context;


    public void M1(){
        context = new Ctx();
        //  do stuff

        //  use some beginInvoke or whatever
        //  to call M2()

        //  do the rest of your stuff
    }

    public void M2(){

        Ctx tmp = context;

        //  do stuff

    }
}
```

Remember that sharing stuff like this may lead to concurrency problems and for that you should create a thread safe context class or be sure to only access the context object in a lock statement. Something similar to:

```
public class Ctx{
    public readonly Object _lock = new Object();

    private int v1 = 0;
    public int V1{
        get{
            lock(_lock)
                return v1;
        }
        set{
            lock(_lock)
                v1 = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, you can do something like this:

```
static void Method2() { }

static void Method1()
{
    var sc = SynchronizationContext.Current;
    sc.Post(delegate { Method2(); }, null);
}
```

I read somewhere that await is implemented similar to his (I can´t find my source unfortunatelly)
Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: I already tryed this, it doesn't work.
But i'm good now, thanks.

Answer (score -1):

To call another method asynchronously I'd create a new thread for that method. Within that thread you can still call a callback method as soon as it's finished.

[Here's a tutorial that might help.](http://www.albahari.com/threading/)

Comment: That's not what i was looking for.

Comment: You're not even mentioning synchronization contexts, which is what the question is all about.  It's not about how to execute a function asynchronously.

Comment: there's a solution with BackgroundWorker objects, which basically are threads too but a lot more convenient. I didn't know the `beginInvoke` thing. It involves concurrency as well though.

Comment: @Servy synchronization contexts are mentioned in the [tutorial](http://www.albahari.com/threading/). But you're right, I should have put it in here explicitly.